# trying to submit rich text editor content in asp.net mvc and getting "potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE in asp.net mvc and getting the error message "a potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected" when trying to save the text from the TinyMCE editor.
I set ValidateRequest="false" both in web.config and on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please re-tag to include "asp.net" and "tinymce"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the ValidateInput attribute to your action and set it to false.

Like this.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Submit(string FormContent)
{

}
```

Comment: Is this a good idea in general? I mean not validating input? Is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

To get this working in ASP.NET MVC 2.0, I also had to add

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

to the

```
<system.web>
```

section of my web.config file